# Can I host my React + Firebase, Firestore application in Amazon EC2?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I have created a react application in which I have used firebase and firestore as a backend and database. I want to host this website in Amazon EC2. Also I would use Amazon S3 along with it. So can I host it in Amazon EC2?
If I can then please explain me the steps to host this application using Amazon EC2.

Also is it safe to host a firebase/firestore involved application in Amazon EC2?

Note :- I don't want to host in Firebase hosting. I want to host in Amazon EC2 only.

Comment: You can host your "firebase/firestore involved (web) application" wherever you want (i.e. at any internet hosting service). The Firebase backend services will be called from the user's browser.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Renaud! 